# Setting OnLongClickListeners to view in listview row intercepts onclick event of listrow

Tags: java, android, listview, focus

each of my listview's rows holds a number of textviews.
Each textview has `singleline` set to `true` and is truncated at the end. 
If a textview is truncated, it should be longclickable by the user to open a popup or toast and print the whole text.

So here is my problem:

As soon as I add the OnLongClickListener to a textview, that is part of a row of a listView, the `onItemClick` method of that listView is not called anymore when the textview is clicked (not longclicked).

XML:

List row item:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leadingText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="20x"/>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ExpandableTextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="5.0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

Adding the onItemClickListener to my listView (this happens in a fragment, that holds my listview):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

            UIListEntry item = (UIListEntry) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if(selectedKey != item.getId()) {
                selectedKey = item.getId();
                view.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                selectedKey = null;
                view.setSelected(false);
                view.setActivated(false);
            }

        }


    });
```

Setting the `onLongClickListener` in my custom TextView `ExpandableTextView`

```
private void init() {
    this.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Layout l = getLayout();
                    if (l != null) {
                        int lines = l.getLineCount();
                        if (lines > 0)
                            if (l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0)
                                addLongClickListener();
                    }
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

private void addLongClickListener() {

    this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(SmlApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to implement an individual `onLongClickListener` for each textview but keep the `onClickListener` for the whole row, so the textview does not intercept it and the row is still selectable? Setting the `onItemLongClickListener` on the listView won't help me, because i don't want the whole row to be longclickable but the individual `ExpandableTextView`